# How to retrieve nested data from Firebase?? App is crashing

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

My Firebase storage looks like this

[image]

I'm able to save under "interest" just fine, but then when I try to retrieve all the data under the user id, the app crashes. I'm new to Firebase and I'm not experienced enough to know how to call all the data(everything: email, location, name, etc AND the child of interest).

Can someone please help me? This is my code:

```
 func fetchUser() {
    guard let uid = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid else {
        //for some reason uid = nil
        return
    }

    FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users").child(uid).observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) in

        if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
            //                self.navigationItem.title = dictionary["name"] as? String

            let user = User()
            user.setValuesForKeysWithDictionary(dictionary)
            self.setUpProfileInformationWithUser(user)
        }

        }, withCancelBlock: nil)
}
```

..

```
 class User: NSObject {
     var id: String?
     var name: String?
     var email: String?
     var profileImageUrl: String?
     var username: String?
     var location: String?
     var userDescription: String?
     var interest : String?
     var interest_description : String?
 }
```

..

```
    2016-11-20 12:50:53.999 Your Niche[34689:1654014] -[__NSDictionaryI                 length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f8bbd00f620
    2016-11-20 12:50:54.052 Your Niche[34689:1654014] *** Terminating         app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-        [__NSDictionaryI length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance                 0x7f8bbd00f620'
    *** First throw call stack:
    (
        0   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001055c9d85 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000107b5cdeb objc_exception_throw + 48
2   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001055d2d3d -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
3   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105518cfa ___forwarding___ + 970
4   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001055188a8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
5   libswiftCore.dylib                  0x000000010810c0c8 _TTSf4g_d___TFSSCfT12_cocoaStringPs9AnyObject__SS + 120
6   libswiftCore.dylib                  0x00000001080cc873 _TFSSCfT12_cocoaStringPs9AnyObject__SS + 19
7   libswiftFoundation.dylib            0x0000000108485d70 _TF10Foundation24_convertNSStringToStringFGSqCSo8NSString_SS + 16
8   Your Niche                          0x0000000103fb2f8b _TToFC10Your_Niche4Users8interestGSqSS_ + 75
9   Foundation                          0x000000010615219b -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:] + 288
10  Foundation                          0x000000010619399e -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValuesForKeysWithDictionary:] + 261
11  Your Niche                          0x0000000103fbe790 _TFFC10Your_Niche21ProfileViewController9fetchUserFT_T_U_FCSo15FIRDataSnapshotT_ + 464
12  Your Niche                          0x0000000103f9fc1c _TTRXFo_oCSo15FIRDataSnapshot_dT__XFdCb_dS__dT__ + 60
13  Your Niche                          0x0000000104081431 __71-[FIRDatabaseQuery observeSingleEventOfType:withBlock:withCancelBlock:]_block_invoke + 37
14  Your Niche                          0x0000000104081731 __92-[FIRDatabaseQuery observeSingleEventOfType:andPreviousSiblingKeyWithBlock:withCancelBlock:]_block_invoke + 110
15  Your Niche                          0x00000001040a7dcf __43-[FChildEventRegistration fireEvent:queue:]_block_invoke.64 + 88
16  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001085fbd9d _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
17  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010861c3eb _dispatch_client_callout + 8
18  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001086041ef _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 1738
19  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001055230f9 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 9
20  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001054e4b99 __CFRunLoopRun + 2073
21  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001054e40f8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 488
22  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000109403ad2 GSEventRunModal + 161
23  UIKit                               0x00000001065a8f09 UIApplicationMain + 171
24  Your Niche                          0x0000000103f857d2 main + 114
25  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010865092d start + 1
    )
    libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
    (lldb)
```

Comment: Can you post your stack trace of your app crash?

Answer (score 0):

Your app is crashing because of `user.setValuesForKeysWithDictionary(dictionary)`. In your class definition, `interest` is simply another attribute but when you retrieve it from Firebase, it actually is a dictionary hence the compiler is unable to map it respectively. Two options I can think of real fast

1. Change `interest` to be a dictionary instead in your class definition
2. Extract the data the old school way as shown below

   ```
   FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users").child(uid).observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) in

   if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
       //                self.navigationItem.title = dictionary["name"] as? String

       guard let email = dictionary["email"] as! String, location = dictionary["location"] as! String, name = dictionary["name"] as! String, imageURL = dictionary["profileImageUrl"] as! String, description = dictionary["userDescription"] as! String, userName = dictionary["username"] as! String, interestDic = dictionary["interest"] as! [String : AnyObject] else
       {
           print("Error extracting FrB data")
           return
       }

       let interest = interestDic["interest"] as String

       let user = User(email, location, imageURL, description, userName, interest)

       self.setUpProfileInformationWithUser(user)
   }
   ```

**Disclaimer: I personally haven't tried the first option but it's worth trying.**

Comment: thanks for the reply, I tried both of those options several times, but it says that User can't accept parameters, so I'm not sure how to fix that.

Comment: Can you post the exact error you get? It might be because you don't have a constructor hence it makes it a requirement to have all attributes assigned for each newly created object

Comment: a lot of errors showed up when I put the code in but the main one was: Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not '[String : AnyObject]' Then when I deleted 'guard', it brought up more errors.

Comment: You might want to look at this answer I had a while back with regards to retrieving Firebase data.. https://stack overflow.com/a/39862631